# Getting error when installing Styled Components for React

Tags: reactjs, npm, styled-components

When running

```sh
npm install --save styled-components
```

got the following message in terminal:

```sh
found 20 vulnerabilities (2 low, 18 moderate)

  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
Jcusick-belm19:PCC App joshua.cusick$ npm audit fix
npm WARN eslint-config-react-app@5.2.0 requires a peer of eslint-plugin-flowtype@3.x but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN tsutils@3.17.1 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

updated 2 packages in 4.972s

47 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

fixed 3 of 20 vulnerabilities in 918673 scanned packages
  17 vulnerabilities required manual review and could not be updated
Jcusick-belm19:PCC App joshua.cusick$ npm install styled-components@^5.0.0 react@^16.8 react-dom@^16.8 react-is@^16.8
npm WARN eslint-config-react-app@5.2.0 requires a peer of eslint-plugin-flowtype@3.x but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN tsutils@3.17.1 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

+ react@16.13.0
+ styled-components@5.0.1
+ react-dom@16.13.0
+ react-is@16.13.0
updated 5 packages and audited 918674 packages in 7.038s
```

....what the heck is happening here?

Comment: Run `npm audit fix` as it suggested

Comment: did that, didnt work